# Bool don't change between widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, boolean

So I am trying to add filters to my calorie tracking app and I encountered this problem. I try to individually change the value of different booleans (ex.: vegan, keto ...) and it changes in the widget that I change them in (Item), but not in the parent (CategoryGrid) widget. Although, the value of _isSelected changes as it is supposed to, the value of categoryType is not reflected in the parent (CategoryGrid) widget.
This is the code:

```
class CategoryGrid extends StatefulWidget {
  Recipe recipe;
  CategoryGrid(this.recipe);

  @override
  State<CategoryGrid> createState() => _CategoryGridState();
}

class _CategoryGridState extends State<CategoryGrid> {
  bool isVegan = false;
  bool isVegetarian = false;
  bool isKeto = false;
  bool isLowFat = false;
  bool isLowCarbs = false;
  bool isLowCalories = false;

  @override
  void setState(VoidCallback fn) {
    isVegan = widget.recipe.isVegan;
    isVegetarian = widget.recipe.isVegetarian;
    isKeto = widget.recipe.isKeto;
    isLowFat = widget.recipe.isLowFat;
    isLowCarbs = widget.recipe.isLowCarbs;
    isLowCalories = widget.recipe.isLowCalories;
    super.setState(fn);
  }

  void changeValue(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      value = !value;
    });
    print(value);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      ...
                Item('Vegan', isVegan, changeValue),
                Item('Vegetarian', isVegetarian, changeValue),
                Item('Low-fat', isLowFat, changeValue),
                Item('Low-carbs', isLowCarbs, changeValue),
                Item('Low-calories', isLowCalories, changeValue),
                Item('Keto', isKeto, changeValue),
             ...
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            ...
            onPressed: () {
              widget.recipe = Recipe(
                id: widget.recipe.id,
                title: widget.recipe.title,
                ingredients: widget.recipe.ingredients,
                steps: widget.recipe.steps,
                servings: widget.recipe.servings,
                description: widget.recipe.id,
                creatorId: widget.recipe.id,
                p: widget.recipe.p,
                c: widget.recipe.c,
                f: widget.recipe.f,
                kcal: widget.recipe.kcal,
                imageUrl: widget.recipe.imageUrl,
                isVegan: isVegan,
                isKeto: isKeto,
                isLowCalories: isLowCalories,
                isLowCarbs: isLowCarbs,
                isLowFat: isLowFat,
                isVegetarian: isVegetarian,
              );
              print(widget.recipe.isKeto);
              print(widget.recipe.isVegan);
              Navigator.of(context).pop(widget.recipe);
            },
            child: const Text('Save filters'),
          ...
  }
}

// The individual item widget

class Item extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data;
  bool categoryType;
  Function changeValue;
  Item(this.data, this.categoryType, this.changeValue);

  @override
  State<Item> createState() => _ItemState();
}

class _ItemState extends State<Item> {
  bool _isSelected = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton.icon(
      ...
      onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _isSelected = !_isSelected;
          widget.categoryType = _isSelected;
        }); 
        widget.changeValue(widget.categoryType);
      },
      ...
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two changes that you have to do:

1. In your `changeValue` function you are updating the value of function parameter `value`, not your bool variables like `isVegan`, `isVegetarian`, etc
2. You are passing isVegan, isVegetarian value to your `Item` widget. Anyway the value which you are setting to `categoryType` in your Item widget will not update the parent variables because dart does not have reference parameters. Arguments are passed as values.

You have to set the `value` to your isVegan, isVegetarian, ... variables by passing a separate function callback like this.

```
Item('Vegan', isVegan, (value) {isVegan = value; }),
Item('Vegetarian', isVegetarian, (value) {isVegetarian = value; }),
... // so on for all your items
```

Answer (score 1):

In your case it was not working because, In below method you are updating the value to true/false

```
 onPressed: () {
        setState(() {
          _isSelected = !_isSelected;
          widget.categoryType = _isSelected;
        }); 
        widget.changeValue(widget.categoryType);
      },
```

And in below method you are again updating it

```
 void changeValue(bool value) {
    setState(() {
      value = !value;
    });
    print(value);
  }
```

So you have two choice, 1. Stop updating value in child 2. Stop updating value in parent. I believe you should stop updating value in child and remove _isSelected  variable from item widget.

```
class Item extends StatefulWidget {
  final String data;
  bool categoryType;
  Function changeValue;
  Item(this.data, this.categoryType, this.changeValue);

  @override
  State<Item> createState() => _ItemState();
}

class _ItemState extends State<Item> {
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ElevatedButton.icon(
 
/// Use the widget.categoryType to make this button selected.
...
      onPressed: () {
       
        widget.changeValue(widget.categoryType);
      },
      ...
    );
  }
}
```